# Creating Shopify cart permalink with mailto

Tags: html-email, liquid, shopping-cart, permalinks, shopify-template

I am trying to setup an href mailto link where the subject or body will be pre-filled with a permalink to a cart filled with products.

To create this cart permalink, here is the code:

```
{% capture productlist %}
  {% for item in cart.items %}
    updates[{{ item.variant.id }}]={{ item.quantity }}{% unless forloop.last %}&{% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

<a href="/cart/update?{{ productlist }}">Cart Page Link</a>
```

This code works perfectly. So now I am trying to incorporate this link into an href mailto:

```
<a href = "mailto:email@gmail.com?subject=shopify-store.com/cart/update? {{ productlist }}"> email@gmail.com </a>
```

But unfortunately, the above href does not work properly for multiple products. It only works for one variant or one product in the cart. I'm assuming it's an issue with how mailto parses the subject or body text.

How could I get this mailto to pre-fill the subject or body with the full cart page permalink for multiple variants or products?

Comment: Could anyone provide any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work. I just needed to encode the URL.